# Combining a wordpress theme with an html theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am new to wordpress development. I was wondering if I am able to combine an existing wordpress theme that I currently have on my website with an html template that I found through themeforest. Would I need to create an entirely new wordpress theme for this? Or could I just import the css files of the html theme and use the html elements accordingly?

Thanks!

Comment: go to themes folder. copy twentyseventeen theme paste it there then rename that theme folder with your name. change theme name in style.css then Activate theme. Now put your html in front-page.php then try to place some code from taht file to header & footer. then call menu to header file and widgets and all other stuff as per your requirement in different files.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your wordpress theme according to your desire by creating a child theme. See this link [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

You can modify the theme according to your desire but you cant just copy paste any html template to wordpress and expect it to work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this - I would assume that if the PHP template is associated to a WordPress page, and the CSS/JS scripts are all loaded - you can in fact copy and paste any html template and expect it to work right? Is there something else needed?